# Recording audio from an Android device

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that records your voice through default mic of the device but I'm running into some complications.

I'm using this line to make it clear the source of audio ( which is MIC )

```
MediaRecorder  mprec = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;

mprec.start();
```

But I face an error in android studio:

> : required android.media.MediaRecorder
>   found : Int (MIC)

It happens when I try to put MIC or anything else after AudioSource.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android Documentation:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();//INTERESTING
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);//INTERESTING
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}

mRecorder.start();
```

Note the `//INTERESTING` comment; That is the key where you see how you should do it.

First you create the MediaRecorder and then apply the audio source as (in your case) the/a microphone.

[source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html)

Comment: oh I totally forgot that , thank you question solved.

Comment: yea I tried at first it told me to wait 3 more minutes :) it worked now